# How to generate a lower frequency version of a signal in Matlab?

Tags: math, matlab, signal-processing, frequency, fft

With a sine input, I tried to modify it's frequency cutting some lower frequencies in the spectrum, shifting the main frequency towards zero. As the signal is not fftshifted I tried to do that by eliminating some samples at the begin and at the end of the fft vector:

```
interval = 1;
samplingFrequency = 44100;
signalFrequency = 440;
sampleDuration = 1 / samplingFrequency;
timespan = 1 : sampleDuration : (1 + interval);
original = sin(2 * pi * signalFrequency * timespan);
fourierTransform = fft(original);
frequencyCut = 10; %% Hertz
frequencyCut = floor(frequencyCut * (length(pattern) / samplingFrequency) / 4); %% Samples
maxFrequency = length(fourierTransform) - (2 * frequencyCut);
signal = ifft(fourierTransform(frequencyCut + 1:maxFrequency), 'symmetric');
```

But it didn't work as expected. I also tried to remove the center part of the spectrum, but it wielded a higher frequency sine wave too.

How to make it right?

Comment: you could try just **downsampling** the signal (resample at lower rate by deleting samples)

Comment: It could work. But which is the best way to do that? With a for loop or with a specific function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@las3rjock:

its more like downsampling the signal itself, not the FFT..
Take a look at **[downsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/downsample.html)**.

Or you could create a [timeseries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html) object, and resample it using the [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) method.

#### EDIT:

a similar example :)

```
% generate a signal
Fs = 200;
f = 5;
t = 0:1/Fs:1-1/Fs;
y = sin(2*pi * f * t) + sin(2*pi * 2*f * t) + 0.3*randn(size(t));

% downsample
n = 2;
yy = downsample([t' y'], n);

% plot
subplot(211), plot(t,y), axis([0 1 -2 2])
subplot(212), plot(yy(:,1), yy(:,2)), axis([0 1 -2 2])
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I read the question to mean that the poster wanted to reduce the absolute frequency of the signal, which could be done in a crude way by downsampling and zero-padding the spectrum, or could be done more precisely by shifting the desired portion of the spectrum.  If you downsample the signal, you actually shift it up in frequency in the DFT's -pi to pi relative frequency axis (until you downsample too much and alias the signal).

Comment: After seeing your latest edit, I think the original poster needs to clarify whether he wants a low-pass-filtered version of the signal (like yours) or a frequency-downshifted version of the signal (like mine).

Comment: @las3rjock you're right, this signal was LPFized. But I still accept his answer for pointing me the resample method =)

Comment: The Resample method resample arrays too, not only timestamp objects as I expected from what you said

Comment: You must be talking about the one in Signal Processing toolbox

Answer (score 2):

A crude way to downsample your spectrum by a factor of `n` would be

```
% downsample by a factor of 2
n = 2; % downsampling factor
newSpectrum = fourierTransform(1:n:end);
```

For this to be a lower-frequency signal on your original time axis, you will need to zero-pad this vector up to the original length on both the positive and negative ends.  This will be made much simpler using fftshift:

```
pad = length(fourierTransform);
fourierTransform = [zeros(1,pad/4) fftshift(newSpectrum) zeros(1,pad/4)];
```

To recover the downshifted signal, you fftshift back before applying the inverse transform:

```
signal = ifft(fftshift(fourierTransform));
```

**EDIT**: Here is a complete script which generates a plot comparing the original and downshifted signal:

```
% generate original signal
interval = 1;
samplingFrequency = 44100;
signalFrequency = 440;
sampleDuration = 1 / samplingFrequency;
timespan = 1 : sampleDuration : (1 + interval);
original = sin(2 * pi * signalFrequency * timespan);

% plot original signal
subplot(211)
plot(timespan(1:1000),original(1:1000))
title('Original signal')

fourierTransform = fft(original)/length(original);

% downsample spectrum by a factor of 2
n = 2; % downsampling factor
newSpectrum = fourierTransform(1:n:end);

% zero-pad the positive and negative ends of the spectrum
pad = floor(length(fourierTransform)/4);
fourierTransform = [zeros(1,pad) fftshift(newSpectrum) zeros(1,pad)];

% inverse transform
signal = ifft(length(original)*fftshift(fourierTransform),'symmetric');

% plot the downshifted signal
subplot(212)
plot(timespan(1:1000),signal(1:1000))
title('Shifted signal')
```

[Plot of original and downshifted signals http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5426/downshift.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5426/downshift.png)